# Checkboxlist AND Others Options in asp.net MVC with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I need create two checkbox lists with Razor(Asp.net MVC), I know create but I need add INPUTS to Add Others options in my list.
See printscreen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNhr.jpg

When I use my submit form I need to send to backend my list and others parameters
I send 3 parameters  (type, name, dimensions).

SOLVED

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Artes"))
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selecionado, new { @class = "icheckbox_minimal" }) @Model.TipoArte   @Model.Medida

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Medida)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MidiaArte)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TipoArte)
```

}

Comment: So what have you got so far? Can you post the code which you've written which isn't working?

Comment: I solved.. thanks man